# Determine existing Directory of Path

Tags: c#, .net, directory, fileinfo

Assume I have an incomplete path-string: `C:\dir\temp\f`
And I have the following filesystem:

```
C:\dir\
c:\dir\temp\
c:\dir\temp\foobar\
c:\dir\temp\foobar2\
c:\dir\temp\bar
```

I want to determine which part of the directory is the best matching. In this example it would be `c:\dir\temp\foobar\` because it starts with the path-string (and `foobar` matches better than `foobar2`). 
how can i efficiently get the available path? Do I have to split up the incomplete path string by `/` and test if the folders are available or is there a better method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, what you want to do is something like `dir C:\dir\temp\f*`. In .Net, you can do this using [`Directory.GetDirectories()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ff71z1w.aspx), but it requires you to split the full path into path and pattern. To do this, you can use methods from the `Path` class. So, your code could look something like:

```
Directory.GetDirectories(
    Path.GetDirectoryName(path), Path.GetFileName(path) + "*")
```

This will return a collection of all matching directories, so you will have to figure out which one of them matches best by yourself.